# WEB API 2 how to set Content-Type server side?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I have a customer that has a specific API design I am required to comply with.  The logic I host with my WEB API code allows the customer to make simple changes to a resource that exists on my system (change, delete etc.).

The interface is very simple:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(OpRequest opRequest)

public class OpRequest
{
    public string op { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

Based on the value of "op", i parse "data" to complete the operation.

My question is related to the Content-type header in their request. They do not send a Content-Type header at all, but the actual data they POST is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for some requests and "application/json". for other requests.  Works fine when they send urlencoded, but throws "415 unsupported media" error when they send JSON.

My thought is that I need to intercept their request, detect the content-type and set it before it reaches my logic, but I am not certain how to do that.  I must use a single operation to accommodate all Content-types.  Is this possible?

Comment: Your last statement is not correct. Client should be sending the content-type and you can write formatters or use default formatter to serialize.

Comment: Right, but the client won't send me the content-type header.  This is my core problem.